# Redis Compatible Reversible Data Structure for a Binary Search?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-modules

I have a chat module coded in Nodejs and Redis, which loads all the DB users into Redis and later retrieve them with the Key and Value, As what redis server is expected to do,

To store them I used "Key" as the User_ID with prefix and values in json as below,

```
entry.user_id = rows[i].user_id;
entry.uname = rows[i].uname.toString();
client.set('chat_userid_' + entry.user_id, JSON.stringify(entry));
```

This works fine, as long as we do searches for the user's data using only the User_ID. Sometimes I have to find user with the "name" as well, In this case, when we want to search via name, I had to do another key to the value list just for that search.

```
entry.user_id = rows[i].user_id;
entry.uname = rows[i].uname.toString();
client.set('chat_uname_' + entry.uname, JSON.stringify(entry));
```

As you can see above Data structure is very low performance and redundant, Is there a better data structure to store the user data in the Redis server, that we can get the same result as per the above use-case?

Comment: Did you consider using the Redis Module https://redisearch.io?